# Enable migration to another context?

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, nuget

I have two DBContext classes in an application. `MyMvcContext` and auto-generated `UserContext`.

I've been developing an web app using `MyMvcContext` for a while. Now I need to modify the class of `UserProfile` which is in context `UsersContex`. I tried to migrate the class change to database and ran the following commands. However, I got error message when running `Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName MyMvc.Models.UsersContext`?

```
PM> Enable-Migrations 
More than one context type was found in the assembly 'MyMvc'.
To enable migrations for MyMvc.Models.UsersContext, use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName MyMvc.Models.UsersContext.
To enable migrations for MyMvc.Models.MyMvcContext, use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName MyMvc.Models.MyMvcContext.
PM> Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName MyMvc.Models.UsersContext
Migrations have already been enabled in project 'MyMvc'. To overwrite the existing migrations configuration, use the -Force parameter.
```

**Update:**
Should I find and replace all `UsersContext` to `MyMvcContext` in my project files?

Comment: my guess: there are changes that imply either a generated migration class will be overwritten or if the DB has data, a column has been removed or chnaged in a way that that column must go.   Give EF permission to kill it or overwrite with -force

Comment: You really got that error message when you tried to run "Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName MyMvc.Models.UsersContext" ? That is a case for report bug...

Comment: @PriscilaMayumiSato Yes, I got the error message. I use only one `DefaultConection` connectionStrings. And I already enabled MyMvcContext. Could it cause the problem?

Comment: @NickW I have a hint: needs disable a migration for a context before enable for another. But... that is crazy. I will to talk with the team, but it is like a bug...I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

Once migrations are enabled for a project.  Do you not use the `Update-Database` - see [Entity Framework Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj554735.aspx)

That's why you are receiving the error, Migrations have already been enabled... once they are enabled you then update the database with the above command.